# TestMethod Skipped, but where is the WS Call?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I'm trying to test a class I'm using with a Trigger. The Trigger fires when events and tasks are created/modified/deleted.

I'm able to test the task creation just fine, but when I try to test the event creation with the code below I'm greeted with a 'Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts, test skipped' message on the line where I'm creating the event.

```
Event e = new Event(subject='Test Event', whatId = account.id, 
          startDateTime = DateTime.valueOf('2014-04-26 14:45:05'), 
          endDateTime = DateTime.valueOf('2014-04-26 14:45:05'));
insert e;

//Verify count = 1
account = [SELECT ID, activity_count__c FROM Account WHERE ID = :account.id];
System.assertEquals(1, account.activity_count__c);
```

I've tried using System.now() to set my dates as well as what you see above. Both provide me with the same results. Any ideas of what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

When you get that message, no line number is reported so the problem is probably occuring on `insert e`.

This contrived code will produce that error:

```
@isTest
public class MyTest {

    @isTest
    static void test() {
        Account a = new Account(Name = ' Acme');
        insert a;
        Event e = new Event(
                Subject = 'Test Event',
                WhatId = a.id, 
                StartDateTime = DateTime.valueOf('2014-04-26 14:45:05'), 
                EndDateTime = DateTime.valueOf('2014-04-26 14:45:05')
                );
        insert e;
    }

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void callout() {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://google.com');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
    }
}
```

where the insert causes some other code (trigger or workflow rule) to make a callout:

```
trigger MyTrigger on Event (before insert) {
    MyTest.callout();
}
```

Assuming you find there is a callout, you can [mock](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm) it in your test to allow your test to run. (If you are not sure where it is, turn on the debug logging and run the test again and check the log.)